# Fuzzy text with Core-Plot and NSViewController

Tags: cocoa, core-plot, nsviewcontroller

I am using an NSViewController to load a nib with a view that renders a Core-Plot chart.  I replace the "target view" using the following code:

```
NSViewController* aViewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib name" bundle:nil];
if (aViewController != nil)
{
    myCurrentViewController = aViewController;
}

// embed the current view to our host view
[myTargetView addSubview: [myCurrentViewController view]];
[[myCurrentViewController view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]];
```

This results in basically everything in the chart looking slightly fuzzy.  I commented out the setFrame and also tried integer values for the setFrame and it made no difference.  The target view also does not have layering on.

If I get rid of the view controller and change myTargetView to the actual chart view class(PlotView) then it is no longer fuzzy.  This is on 10.8.  Any idea why using the NSViewController route is messing up the chart view?

Update #1:  I am using from the Plot_Gallery_Mac sample project the PlotGalleryController, PlotView, PlotItem, and VerticalBarChart to generate the chart through an NSViewController.  I am guessing the setup in the sample PlotItem class (particularly the renderInView method) is not compatible with using it with an NSViewController.

Comment: Is this on a Retina display? If so, how does it look on a standard display?

Comment: As I recall this was a problem early on with the code base. I haven't followed it in the last year or so and can't tell you whether that's been fixed. Search the project's bug history and documentation for "fuzzy/blurry text" to make sure you're not mishandling.

Comment: It is on a retina display but that does not explain why it looks perfect when I get rid of the NSViewController and simply have the PlotView specified in the main nib/window to begin with.  I am using a stripped down PlotGalleryController that calls renderInView when you set the plotItem.  I am investigating now if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Are there any examples of Core Plot using an NSViewController to load the external nib and display the graph?

Comment: @Eric A sample project showing the problem is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sv0qjxiwpoh81yr/1KbiSr38OA/Plot_ViewController_Mac.zip) Note that I called "display" on the chart view for testing purposes.

Comment: The graph didn't stay on screen long enough for me to see the issue you're talking about. One observation, though. I think you need to uncomment the `-setFrame:` line so the hosting view gets positioned properly in its superview.